# How to display twitter feeds in my umbraco website?

Tags: twitter, umbraco

I want to display twitter status of our customer site, but I need to give the control to him to change the twitter account. How to achieve this task? Please anyone give me a idea.

I already use twitter widget but it displays with header and I cant give control with username.

I use utweets package but it also don't have to to change the user account with user name.

Please anyone suggest a good way to display twitter feeds.

Answer (score 3):

Get api credentials here: https://dev.twitter.com/

Get TweetSharp from nuget and then you can use this razor code for inspiration:

```cs
@using TweetSharp
@functions
{

    private TwitterService GetAuthenticatedService()
    {
        var _consumerKey = "XXX";
        var _consumerSecret = "XXX";
        var _accessToken = "XXX";
        var _accessTokenSecret = "XXX";

        var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);
        return service;
    }

}
@{
    var account = "YOURACCOUNT";
    var tweets = new List<TwitterStatus>();
    const int take = 3;
    try
    {
        var service = GetAuthenticatedService();
        tweets = service.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions() { Count = take, ScreenName = "k_h_schneider" }).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}


<div class="box box-no-padding">
    <div class="box-content">
        <div id="twitterFeed">
            @if (tweets != null)
            {
                foreach (var tweet in tweets)
                {
                    <div class="tweet">
                        <small class="text-muted">@tweet.CreatedDate</small>
                        <div class="tweetContent">
                            @Html.Raw(tweet.TextAsHtml)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both">
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tweet sharp and umbraco  packages  have Newtonsoft.json dll, so it makes the problem. my app will crashed due to this error of could not load types of umbraco.

Comment: You can get the source code for tweetsharp and then compile to the version umbraco uses or set the newtonsoftversion in the web.config like in dependentAssembly

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [uTwit package](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/utwit/) on the [Our Umbraco](https://our.umbraco.org) community site.

> uTwit is a combination of two packages to allow you to easily embedd
>   twitter statuses on your website.

Comment: It is  not working  with  umbraco 7.2.5. Installation and adding in to a document type working fine. but while  Authorize it shows the error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." how to solve this problem.

Comment: There is a forum at the bottom of the page for support.

Comment: i find the best solution for this problem. TweetMoaSharp is best one for umbraco 7.2.5 to showing twitter status

Answer (score 0):

I'm using some small code that i obtained from http://social.skybrud.dk/twitter/endpoints/statuses/user-timeline/ that is causing Umbraco 7.5 to come back with `Compilation error - TwitterTimelineResponse response = service.Statuses.GetUserTimeline("xxxxxxxxxx");`.